# Using Excel ActiveX scroll bars while in slide show mode in Powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerpoint, import, slideshow, activex

I have an Excel sheet which has a chart in it along with ActiveX scroll bar commands and some simple macros. The scroll bars are used to change the source data series of the chart and change the chart accordingly. All source data series used by the chart are included in the sheet.

I want to import the sheet in a powerpoint pptx file and be able to use the Excel scroll bars while in the slide show mode of powerpoint.

I haven't found a way to do that. When in the slide show mode the Excel scroll bars are not ... scrollable any more. :)

(using office 2007 or office 2010)

Any help?